# Nature of a wave

Tags: waves

We have two transverse wave

$$y_1= A\sin(kx-\omega t)$$

$$y_2=-A\sin(kx+\omega t)$$

These two waves superposed. Then, at point $x=0$ the equation would be

$$y_1 + y_2 =-2A\sin\omega t.$$

Now how can we know at $x=0$ is node, antinode or neither of them .

In my book it is given as antinode .

Comment: @JohnRennie yes they are moving in opposite direction

Comment: It appears you have made a mistake in your solution. Please see hint below.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint(1)**: 
\begin{align}
\sin(kx-\omega t)+\sin(kx+\omega t)&=\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)-\cos(kx)\sin(\omega t)+\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)+\cos(kx)\sin(\omega t)\\
&=2\sin(kx)\cos(\omega t)
\end{align}

**Hint(2)**:

> By definition, the nodes are when the quantity $\sin(kx)=0$.

**Spoiler! Hover over yellow for answer.**

> That is, they are located at the $x_n$ such that $$kx_n=n\pi$$ 
> where $n=0,\pm 1,\pm 2\cdots$. That is, $$x_n=\frac{n\pi}{k}$$
> are where the nodes are located.

Comment: But why we can add like , when x=0 $y_1=Asin(- \omega t)$ and $y_2=-Asin\omega t$ and add hoth of them .

Comment: In my book it is given as antinode. How ?

Comment: Sorry , I have edited my question

Comment: @user123733 To avoid possible errors due to lack of spatial information ($x$-behavior), you must add the functions before applying any specific values of $x$ or $t$.

Comment: @BillN but in my book it is written as antinode .

Comment: @user123733 You completely changed the question, so you changed the solution from node to antinode. Given your equation `-2Asin(wt)` at x=0, it should be obvious that it's an antinode since the y position changes sinusoidally with an amplitude of the sum of the two other waves. This means x=0 is a point where maximum displacement occurs, which is the condition for an antinode.

Comment: @Steve at antinode y position should be maximum but here it can vary with time .

Comment: @user123733 Yes the position of an antinode changes with time, it doesn't stay fixed at the maximum, it only takes on that maximum value at specific times. A node stays fixed in place, but an *anti*node moves the largest possible amount over time. There are likely some YouTube videos that can demonstrate an antinode visually over time.